# Python3 Dictionary Style Object Mapping To JSON Serializeable

Tags: python, json, serialization

I am working on a simple employee system for learning Object Oriented Programming in Python3.
My script works as i expected, excluding saving and loading employee dictionary.
The problem is my dictionary is not a normal dictionary cause of this code : 
`Employees[eid] = Employee(eName,eSalary,eAge)`
I want to make this database JSON Serializeable but i have no idea nor i found it on internet.

Sadly the code adding system in stack overflow gave me cancer so i pasted my code to gist :
https://gist.github.com/ShockvaWe/d82d89f767506c1ff682a4cc387d1597

And my error message with current code is (its basic TypeEroor but ...) :
Sorry but i waste my 2 hours trying to paste my code and i fail so i get mad.Thanks for the edit and answers.

Here is the code:

```
## -*- coding=<utf-8> -*-
import json 
from json import JSONEncoder
Employees = {}
print(type(Employees))
class Employee(object): 
    'Common base for all employes'
    empCount = 0
    def __init__(self,name,salary,age): 
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.age = age
        Employee.empCount += 1

    def displayCount(self):
        print ("Total Employee : " , Employee.empCount , "\n")

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print("Name : ", self.name ," Salary : " , self.salary ," Age : " , self.age, "\n")
print ("NEVER FORGET TO SAVE YOUR CHANGES ! \n")
print ("Press s to save your work ! \n")
print ("Press l to load database. \n")
print ("Press x for adding employee \n")
print ("Press y for show employee count \n")
print ("Press z for display employee \n")
print ("Press q for quitting. \n")
while True :
    st = input("->> : ")
    if (st == "x"):
        eid = input ("Id : ")
        eName = input ("\nName : ")
        eSalary = input ("\nSalary : ")
        eAge = input ("\nAge : \n")
        Employees[eid] = Employee(eName,eSalary,eAge)
    if (st == "y"):
        print("Total Employee Count : " , Employee.empCount)
    if (st == "z"):
        wantedId = input("Give the id : ")
        Employees[wantedId].displayEmployee()
    if (st == "q"):
        exit()
    if (st == "s"):
        with open('myfile.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(dict(Employees),f)
    if (st == "l"):
        with open('myfile.json') as f:
            Employees = json.load(f)
    if (st == 'f'):
        print("roger dodger")
```

Comment: If you want your question answered, you probably shouldn't insult the website you're posting it on. I would advise editing your post to be more polite.

Comment: Please edit your question and remove the last paragraph. Its offensive and unrelated to your question. Try to edit it again and include your code. You know, a lot of people use this site and can write well-formatted questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little example that probably reproduces the `TypeError` you are seeing:

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, arg):
    self.arg = arg

d = {'key1': Foo('some arg')}
import json

print json.dumps(d)
```

By their nature, Python `class` instances are not serializable. Assuming you want the data within the class, one option would be to use the instance dictionary instead of the class object:

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, arg):
    self.arg = arg

f = Foo('some arg')
d = {'key1': f.__dict__}
import json

print json.dumps(d)
```

Result:

```
{"key1": {"arg": "some arg"}}
```

To deserialize, you can use a sequence in your DB and get this to construct new Employee objects, and keep track of this in your JSON when "reconstituting" them later:

```
import json

class Employee(object):
  def __init__(self, arg, emp_id=None):
    self.emp_id = emp_id or self.get_id()
    self.arg = arg

  def get_id(self):
    """
    This example assumes you have a db query module and some kind of Sequence 
    definition that looks like this (I am using postgres here) :

      Sequence "your_app.employee_id_seq"
        Column     |  Type   |          Value           
    ---------------+---------+--------------------------
     sequence_name | name    | employee_id_seq
     last_value    | bigint  | 1204
     start_value   | bigint  | 1
     increment_by  | bigint  | 1
     max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807
     min_value     | bigint  | 1
     cache_value   | bigint  | 1
     log_cnt       | bigint  | 31
     is_cycled     | boolean | f
     is_called     | boolean | t
    """
    return your_db_module.query("SELECT nextval('employee_id_seq'::regclass)")
```

A Test:

```
f = Employee('some arg')
d = {f.emp_id: f.__dict__}
# We could add as many employees as we like to serialized, but I am just using one here:
serialized = json.dumps(d)
deserialized_employees = json.loads(serialized)
print deserialized_employees
employee_objects = []
for k, v in deserialized_employees.items():
  # assert int(k) == int(v['emp_id']) - a check if you want to be paranoid
  # Now that we have an ID, we can use the kwarg for emp_id to construct the right object
  e = Employee(v['arg'], emp_id=int(k))
  employee_objects.append(e)

print employee_objects[0]
```

Result:

```
<__main__.Employee object at 0x10dca6b50>
```

Note that you may need to define custom `__cmp__` and/or `__eq__` methods in order to allow your unique `emp_id` to be the defining characteristic of a unique employee, since at this current state, we are technically allowed to create many instances of the same employee using a single ID (usually a bad thing.) Not sure if that will come into play for your case, but it is worth considering.

Comment: Yes, but now how do you deserialize this back into the right object?

Comment: Since this is related to a DB, I would suggest an auto-incrementing sequence to act as the unique identifier for the Employee, then pass this into the initialization of each object, and use that as a basis for deserializing later. You could simply construct the employee based on the dict you have.

Comment: Could you make deserialize too ?

Comment: Yeah @NickyRomero - I'll add in a `get_id()` method and show an example DB setup for the id.